Spring-Boot-Kafka: how to set topic-configs in java
I am using Spring-Boot with Kafka.
Parts of pom.xml
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
...

Kafka-listner
@KafkaListener (topics = "X_OUT", autoStartup = "true")
public void listenTo (ConsumerRecord <String, String> cr, @Header (KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic)
{
  // ...
}

After my program starts it created the topics I use automatically.
The usage of Kafka is fine - all is working as expected.
But I need to change the configuration of the topics - because of reasons.
./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe
Topic: X_OUT    TopicId: 0Rt8Sh7_RSO60O0BlQ2Zyw PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor:      1   Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
  Topic: X_OUT  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0

I need to change the topic that way.

min.insync.replicas to 1
ReplicationFactor to 4

Is it possible to set that in the app by Java?
The only way I found was by console-tools of Kafka.
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name X_OUT --add-config min.insync.replicas=1

kafka-reassign-partitions.sh ... // a json-file

I do not want to use the console-tools but do it automatically in the app (at the creation or by altering).

See if declaring NewTopic as bean works for you:
@Bean
public NewTopic topic3() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("thing3")
            .assignReplicas(0, List.of(0, 1))
            .assignReplicas(1, List.of(1, 2))
            .assignReplicas(2, List.of(2, 0))
            .config(TopicConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "zstd")
            .build();
}

More in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/configuring-topics.html
